# webpack import module not found error: Uncaught TypeError: _useFetch__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["default"](...) is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a problem with this code block. I tried so many thing but not worked at all. When I import this file, I am getting following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _useFetch__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["default"](...) is null
```

`npm start` runs well and webpack compiles with no error:

```
javascript modules 5.33 KiB
  ./src/components/Home.js 3.97 KiB [code generated]
  ./src/useFetch.js 1.36 KiB [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.72.0 compiled successfully in 292 ms
```

useFetch file

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useFetch = (url) => {
  const [data, setBlogs] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => { setBlogs(data) })
      .catch(err => console.log(err.message));
  }, [url]);

  return data;
}

export default useFetch;
```

Home Component

```
import useFetch from "../useFetch";

const Home = () => {
  // FIXME: ERROROOOARO HERE
  const { data: blogs } = useFetch('http://localhost:8000/blogs');
  ...
}
```

Comment: Please write the correct title of your question.

Comment: I don't think this is the cause of the import issue, but you might want to add a dependency array with `url` to the `useEffect` hook so you don't trigger render looping because the effect updates the `data` state unconditionally.

Comment: i tried it but no help :(

Answer (score 0):

That useFetch is going to enter into a loop because as no dependencies are provided to the useEffect and you do a setState inside, then it will trigger itself.

Regarding the import, please try doing:

```
export { useFetch };
```

and

```
import { useFetch }  from '../useFetch';
```

Comment: why .jsx ,up to today i never use .jsx at my apps ? and i added dep array like ,[url]

Comment: Why should the `useFetch` file use the `.jsx` extension, if all it is is the `useFetch` function it doesn't return any React code or JSX? `.js` vs `.jsx` generally doesn't matter other than giving you a different file icon in the IDE.

Comment: same opinion +1

Comment: i solved it with useState([]) instead useState(null), after so long time i did it :D oh yes.

Comment: Ohh, that was the issue. You can also use undefined instead of null.